# UPSERT including select from another table over a list of data

Tags: mysql, loops, sql-update, sql-insert, upsert

I have a long set of data, which should be inserted (or updated), respective if the data is present or not.

I got this far, but have no idea if I am on the right track. Maybe some MySQL expert knows how to finish the statement or correct it.

I have two tables:

Areas

| id | number | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4578 | FirstArea |
| 2 | 4328 | SomeArea |
| 3 | 3214 | SecondArea |

Customers

| id | first_name | last_name | identifier | area_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | James | Jameson | HJ238 | 1 |
| 2 | Pepper | Potts | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | Peter | Parker | NULL | 2 |
| 4 | Anis | Abraham | NULL | NULL |
| 5 | Karl | Klux | HI438 | NULL |

I want to insert or update the table `Customers` with customer data. I got this far, so far:

```
set @last_name="James", @first_name="Jameson", @identifier="HZ732732", @cc="FirstArea";
set @last_name="Abraham", @first_name="Anis", @identifier="JI72373", @cc="SecondArea;
set @last_name="Potts", @first_name="Pepper", @identifier="KI83282", @cc="SomeArea;

set @id = (SELECT id from Customers c WHERE c.first_name = @first_name AND e.last_name = @last_name;);
set @cc_id = (SELECT id FROM Areas a WHERE aa.number = @cc;);
INSERT INTO Customers c (id, first_name, last_name, identifier, area_id) values (@id, @first_name, @last_name, @identifier, @cc_id)
ON DUPLICATE key UPDATE e.identifier = @identifier, e.area_id = @cc_id;
```

Here in a fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cb988e

For the loop portion I have no idea and if this works as intended with the variables, I am not sure.

I do not only have three entries but ca. 450 entries to be inserted.

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), especially "5. Some Additional Suggestions" and "C. Consider providing an SQL Fiddle or DB Fiddle". Also provide "Customer Data I have in a seperate file" content (2-3 rows, code-formatted) and desired final data state for provided source deata and file content.

Comment: Here is the fiddle (added in the question as well):
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cb988e

Comment: Well, now please read 2nd sentence in my comment and provide according information.

Comment: Sorry, I think that sentence is misleading. The data "in the seperate file" are the first three ```set``` rows I wrote down (and the 450 more entries). The entries are als formatted in the same way, the three set entries are formatted.

Comment: *The data "in the seperate file" are the first three set rows I wrote down (and the 450 more entries).* ?? Do you mean that your file contains not clear data but shown ready-to-use SQL code?

Comment: Well, with Search&Replace I generated the sql code from the data. Yes.
I just cant figure out how to use the code on each row.

Comment: If the file contains ready-to-use code then you'd load this file into temptable (LOAD_DATE) or variable (LOAD_PICTURE), parse to the fragments (lines?) which must be executed separately then execute them using dynamic SQL (PREPARE).

Answer (score 0):

Investigate:

```
CREATE TABLE Customers(
  id int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  -- added
  first_name VARCHAR(55),
  last_name VARCHAR(55),
  identifier VARCHAR(55),
  area_id int unsigned,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY area_id (area_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Areas(
  id int unsigned NOT NULL,
  number VARCHAR(55),
  area_name VARCHAR(55),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO Customers VALUES
(1, 'James', 'Jameson', 'HJ238', 1),
(2, 'Pepper', 'Potts',NULL, NULL),
(3, 'Peter', 'Parker', NULL, 2),
(4, 'Anis', 'Abraham',NULL, NULL),
(5, 'Karl', 'Klux','HI438', NULL);
SELECT * FROM Customers;

INSERT INTO Areas VALUES
(1, '4578', 'FirstArea'),
(2, '4328', 'SomeArea'),
(3, '3214', 'SecondArea');
SELECT * FROM Areas;
```

> ```
> Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

| id | first_name | last_name | identifier | area_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | James | Jameson | HJ238 | 1 |
| 2 | Pepper | Potts | *null* | *null* |
| 3 | Peter | Parker | *null* | 2 |
| 4 | Anis | Abraham | *null* | *null* |
| 5 | Karl | Klux | HI438 | *null* |

> ```
> Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

| id | number | area_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4578 | FirstArea |
| 2 | 4328 | SomeArea |
| 3 | 3214 | SecondArea |

```
-- the value (a row from the file) was loaded by some way
-- assigning it to the variable
SET @sql := 'set @last_name="James", @first_name="Jameson", @identifier="HZ732732", @cc="FirstArea";';

-- and execute
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DROP PREPARE stmt;

SELECT @last_name, @first_name, @identifier, @cc; -- check the result
```

> ```
> Statement prepared
> ```

| @last_name | @first_name | @identifier | @cc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| James | Jameson | HZ732732 | FirstArea |

```
set @id = (SELECT id from Customers c WHERE c.first_name = @first_name AND c.last_name = @last_name);
set @cc_id = (SELECT id FROM Areas a WHERE a.number = @cc);

SELECT @id, @cc_id; -- print for debugging purposes

INSERT INTO Customers (id, first_name, last_name, identifier, area_id) 
values (@id, @first_name, @last_name, @identifier, @cc_id)
ON DUPLICATE key UPDATE identifier = @identifier, area_id = @cc_id;
```

| @id | @cc_id |
| --- | --- |
| *null* | *null* |

```
SELECT * FROM Customers;
```

| id | first_name | last_name | identifier | area_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | James | Jameson | HJ238 | 1 |
| 2 | Pepper | Potts | *null* | *null* |
| 3 | Peter | Parker | *null* | 2 |
| 4 | Anis | Abraham | *null* | *null* |
| 5 | Karl | Klux | HI438 | *null* |
| 6 | Jameson | James | HZ732732 | *null* |

```
-- next lines to be prepared/executed with further queries pack execution
SET @sql := 'set @last_name="Abraham", @first_name="Anis", @identifier="JI72373", @cc="SecondArea";';
SET @sql := 'set @last_name="Potts", @first_name="Pepper", @identifier="KI83282", @cc="SomeArea";';
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TIXLLB-u)

---

PS. A lot of minor misprints and errors was fixed - compare with your code char-by-char.